# On a parallelizable manifold, is there always a frame satisfying $[X_i,X_j]=0$?

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $M$ be a parallelizable manifold.

1. Is there always a global frame $(X_i)$ such that $[X_i,X_j]=0$ for all $i,j$ ?
2. If the answer is no, what kind of obstruction there is to find such a frame ? and what kind of condition on $M$ makes it possible to find such a frame ?

Comment: I have the feeling that it is not possible in general. The Lie bracket one is stronger since is related to an integrability condition while the first one is of topological nature. Please let me know if someone gives a decent answer.